# How to map a class to an existing table with the same name when the table is not already pluralized?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm working with an existing database. I've a table called `ClientCode`, i.e. the table itself is not pluralized.

If I create a class called `iHROrgCode`, will Entity Framework map it to the table with the same name? If not, what should I do to get the result?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your DB Context -> `OnModelCreating` method, add the following line

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<iHROrgCode>().ToTable("ClientCode");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```